# Accept/Reject CTA buttons on cards

Tags: buttons, lists, cards, tab, cta

I have to design a dashboard to help sellers to manage invoices addressed to them during the month. The invoices will arrive in "To do" tab. For each invoice we have two choices : "Accept" or "Reject" the document. When a document is rejected or accepted it moves to the appropriate section ("Rejected" tab or "Accepted" tab).

In "To do" tab I don't have any problem, I put two CTA buttons in each card ("Accept" and "Reject") with a high emphasis treatment on "Accept" button (which is positive and must common action).

[image]

My problem is for "Accepted" Tab (and the same for "Rejected"). The seller can see a list of accepted invoices but he can reconsider and refuse an invoice or just remove the Accepted state of it. For these cards I don't know how to design the buttons. I putted 2 outlined buttons (without high emphasis) and I do not know if it's understandable. Should I change and put contained button for one of the two ?

Please help me !

[image]

Comment: You can leave just a single action (REJECT) in Accepted tab. Accepted mark isn't button, but looks very similar to it. Transform the mark to a small supportive indicator, as you already have the tab named "Accepted".

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko I put an "Accepted" button for the case where the user want to take off the "accepted" label and put it back to "To do" tab. Maybe this use case is too specific and does not reflect the reality of use ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the [To Do] tab as your original tasks to complete. Once an invoice is moved to either [Accepted] or [Rejected], the task is considered done and in its final state.

Therefore, if a task is under [Accepted], the use can either [Reject] or move it back to original list, meaning [Move back to To Do].

The [✓Accepted] status for an accepted invoice is unnecessary since (1) It looks like a button and as such is not descriptive as to what would happen if I click it, and (2) it's unnecessary as an indicator since the user already knows they are in the Accepted tab.

If moving an invoice from Accepted to Rejected or back to To Do is not a frequent task, I would also consider hiding those options under a [...] button. Giving you more space for whatever information or more relevant actions you might want to surface.

[image]

Comment: @Woj The problem with this is that it's a bit wordy.

Comment: @Solomon what do you mean ?

Comment: It's 5 words as opposed to 1.

Answer (score 0):

What about "Reject" and "Unaccept"?

Or what about radio buttons "Undecided", "Rejected", and "Accepted"? The question would be that of when tasks should switch tabs.

Comment: "Unaccept"looks to similar to "Accept"

Comment: True. Your idea looked even more similar, though. :)

Comment: Yes true :) that's why I like the solution of Nicolas